# Is there any way to check that why recaptcha is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter and recaptche on register page was working fine but now it show me error

"Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Captcha.(recaptcha)"

i am not getting that how to solve this error as previously recaptcha was working fine 
can it be some js issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codeigniter Validation error: "Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Captcha. (recaptcha)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821994/codeigniter-validation-error-unable-to-access-an-error-message-corresponding-t)

Answer (score 0):

The message you're getting is because the validation rules defined for this field with `$this->form_validation->set_rules` contain a rule which is not passing AND there's no message defined for such rule.

Most likely it's a custom rule.

You'd need to work on your language file (`system/language/english/form_validation_lang.php`) and add a message tailored for your specific rule. If the custom validation rule is called `recaptcha` (your `set_rules` would read something like `$this->form_validation->set_rules('field_name', 'description', 'required|recaptcha');` or something similar), your language file would need a new entry similar to this:

`$lang['form_validation_recaptcha] = 'The {field} field must contain a valid recaptcha response';` or something along those lines.